# 302 redirect on success page

Tags: magento2, checkout

I am placing an order using the bank transfer payment method and when I watch the network traffic, I can see that I get a 302 redirect to the cart on my `checkout/onepage/success` page. It used to work just fine and suddenly stopped. Any idea what might be causing this behaviour or where to look?

The logs do not show anything suspicious. It happens with the default bank transfer payment.

**Magento 2.1.12**

Comment: Hello @Arnie, Do you find the solution?